# How to Serialize Circular References with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given a class like the following that has self-references (via a join table):

```
class User {
  List<User> followers;
  List<User> leaders;

  // Getters and Setters...
}
```

How can I configure Jackson to allow for bi-directional serialization? Using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` allows for serialization of only the field/getter annotated with `@JsonManagedReference`.

Comment: List of followers should be serialized to an array with User as its elements.

Answer (score 0):

For full identity handling, you would want to use `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation. It allows handling of cyclic dependencies more generally, and not just for strict parent/child relationship.

Comment: I previously annotated the User class with `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")` where id is a unique property in each User instance. Even with this annotation serialization failed due to circular references. Did I configure the annotation wrong, or rather should it be placed on the List fields?

Comment: They should be defined just for `User` class/interface, since there is no way to only use these for contents of particular `List` or `Map`. For POJOs it is possible to alternatively define them for fields. But one common issue is when serializing `List` as root values (that is, as the value serialized by `ObjectMapper`). This may lead to issues with Java Type Erasure, and the best practice is (IMO) that one always uses a POJO as root value, as this ensures that full `List` type is available. It is possible to make `List` root value work, just bit more work.